# Terminal doesn't start properly. bash command not found

Tags: macos, bash

I have problems with my terminal after trying to install Homebrew on my Mac. When I start the terminal I get :

```
-bash: touch: command not found
```

When I do `echo $PATH` I get:

```
/usr/local/bin:??
```

I've tried several suggestions like

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

and then it works, but when I restart my terminal, it starts all over.

Comment: Check your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files in your home directory.

Comment: if you have remotely logged into system --> check .bash_profile , if you have already logged into machine --> check .bashrc

Comment: try this command in your terminal ==> `cat ~/.bash_profile `, all the statements in this file will be executed when you logged into the terminal

Comment: This is in my .bash_profile:# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH=’/usr/local/bin:??
export PATH=’/usr/local/bin:??
export PATH=’/usr/local/bin:??   Should I delete the last three "export Path's"?

Comment: you can keep all the paths in a single PATH variable, like the way you have exported. `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: do you even have it installed ... which bash ?

Comment: maybe you just need to source ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), .bash_profile is executed for login shells, while .bashrc is executed for interactive non-login shells.

**Mac OS X** runs a login shell by default for each new terminal window, calling .bash_profile instead of .bashrc.

Setup your PATH variable in .bash_profile

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

correct PATH variable with below single line(which is working fine as per the question)

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: @EAM26, good to see the issue getting fixed. Can you mark the question as solved by clicking check mark beside the answer. This link shows how to that ==> http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer